# Jersey: forbid unspecified parameters

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm developing REST API with Jersey as JAX-RS implementation.

In every resource I explicitly define expected parameters:

```
@GET
@Path("/someData")
public Response getSomeData(
                @QueryParam("id") final Long id,
                @QueryParam("name") final String name) {
...
}
```

There are a number of fixed parameters, which are common for all resources (e.g. "locale").

Is there any way (I'm ok with introducing Jersey-specific dependencies) I can forbid any parameters that belong neither to method parameters nor to the common parameters?

So for example if user invokes

`/api/resource/someData?id=10&locale=en` - he gets the data, but if he invokes

`/api/resource/someData?id=10&locale=en&fakeParam=AAA` - status 400 is returned, with content stating that `fakeParam` is unknown parameter.

Currently second request is processed the same way as the first one, and `fakeParam` is simply ignored.

I think described validation will help users of my API to spot bugs earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do this with JAX-RS but you could easily roll your own solution. This is a bit cumbersome but you could do something like:

```java
@Path("/api")
public class Service {

  @Context
  UriInfo uriInfo;

  ImmutableSet<String> commonParams = ImmutableSet.of("locale");

  @GET
  @Path("validate")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String validate(@QueryParam("foo") String param) {
    Set<String> validParams = newHashSet(commonParams);

    class Local {};
    for (Annotation[] annotations: Local.class.getEnclosingMethod().getParameterAnnotations()) {
      for (Annotation annotation: annotations) {
        if (annotation instanceof QueryParam) {
          validParams.add(((QueryParam)annotation).value());
        }
      }
    }

    if (!difference(uriInfo.getQueryParameters().keySet(), validParams).isEmpty()) {
      //throw an unknown parameter exception
    }

    return "hello";
  }
```

And if you're using Guice or some other AOP tool with Jersey you could probably put this into an aspect s.t. you wouldn't have to add boilerplate to every method you want to validate.

Comment: I'm using spring, so in theory your solution should work. However I would like to avoid messing with AOP configuration and developing this sort of custom logic.